# SSRS - fonts are not emedded into pdf files

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, fonts, embed, ssrs-2017

I am using SSRS 2017 to generate reports, I've installed a new font to use with the reports but the font is getting embedded in all files types except the pdf files.

Here are the font details:

[image: font details]

When I try to download the report from the preview window in visual studio I get the pdf with the right font but when trying to download the same report from the report server I get the report with `Sans Serif` font

**from priview window:**

[image]

[image]

**from report server:**

[image]

[image]

I found some answers referring to the font embeddability but I tried another font with `installable` embeddability and I got the same problem

any idea how to embed the font with the pdf files?

Comment: I assume the font is installed on the SSRS server? Also, that does not look like SSRS 2008, you should update the tags to match what you are actually using.

Comment: I am using my local machine as the SSRS server and I installed the font on my machine, and yes you're right I found out that the SSRS is SSRS 2017, not 2008, I've edited it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've installed the font on my local machine, which I use as my SSRS server, but I found out that the server is running on the admin user while the font was installed for a non-admin user
problem is solved when I installed it for all windows users

[image]

Comment: Glad you solved it. You should mark your own answer as accepted. This will help others find this answer more easily.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I will but I have to wait cause Stackoverflow says I can accept my own answers after 2 days of posting them

Comment: Thank you, you cracked it like Sherlock holmes.